# Remove a Container using a switch flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, What I am looking to do is remove a container if the switch is in the ON position and reappear the container in the OFF position. I created the switch and the container inside a stateful widget. the code is below.

```
Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Switch(value: ads,
                      onChanged: (value){
                        setState(() {
                          ads = value;
                          print(value);
                        });
                      },
                      activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                      activeColor: Colors.green,

                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100.0, 0.0, 5.0, 10.0)),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("Remove the red container if switch is ON"),

                ),
```

A image of the following is below[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `Container` section with the following

```
!ads ? Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Text("Remove the red container if switch is ON"),

) : SizedBox(),
```

Comment: it did work. How can I make this a global variable so if the same container is in different files all of them will be acted from that one switch?

Comment: Create a different dart file to contain your global variables